# Покрасить-накрасить

Tags: грамотная-речь

Если речь идет, например, о заборе, машине или волосах, мы говорим "покрасить", но если имеем в виду макияж, то — "накрасить глаза". Почему употребляются разные предлоги?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Глагол **покрасить** имеет значение 'окрасить, выкрасить': *покрасить дом, крышу, забор, машину; покрасить шерсть в синий цвет; покрасить волосы*. 
Глагол **накрасить** используется в значении 'покрыть, намазать краской (губы, щёки и т.п.)': *накрасить губы, накрасить глаза*. 
Разные здесь не предлоги, а приставки. Они и придают глаголам разное значение.

Comment: Да ясно, что приставки! Это я машинально написала, прошу прощения.