# Красила или накрасила? Какая разница?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как будет правильно: **"я накрасила брови"** или **"я красила брови"**?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/3976/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c

Comment: @shampar, Там покрасить-накрасить, а у нас красить-накрасить.

Comment: Я не говорю, что повтор. Тов. Zholdybaevой будет полезно.

Answer (score 1):

Я красила, красила и наконец накрасила (свои брови).

Сравните: "Мы строили, строили и наконец построили" (из мультфильма «Чебурашка и крокодил Гена»).

*Красить* — глагол несовершенного вида, *накрасить* — глагол совершенного вида.

[38. Глаголы совершенного и несовершенного вида. Правила:](https://school-assistant.ru/?predmet=russian&theme=glagoli_sovershennogo_I_nesovershennogo_vida)

> Глаголы **несовершенного** вида обозначают длительные или повторяющиеся действия, без указания на их завершенность.
>   В неопределенной форме они отвечают на вопрос что делать?. 
>   Например: петь, кипеть, бежать, мечтать, перечитывать, подпрыгивать
>
> Глаголы **совершенного** вида указывают на завершенность действия, его результат, конец действия или его начало. В неопределенной форме они отвечают на вопрос что сделать?. 
>   Например: добежать, купить, зазвенеть, построить, запеть.